# solving linear function in python from nested list

Tags: python

I have a nested list and I need to solve a linear function from its values.

> I used for loop but answer is incorrect as below.
>
> ```
> NL=[[0, 2, 2, 2],
>  [0, 6, 7, 1],
>  [0, 10, 12, 0]]
> for a in NL:
>     ss= ((5*x1) + (3*x2) - (29*x3) - (8*x4))
>     print(ss)
> ```

I need min of ss subject to NL

Comment: `x1`, `x2`, `x3` and `x4`  is not defined

Comment: Yes, sorry it is defined in the rest of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more clarity on what you're trying to achieve would be good.

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```py
NL = [
    [0, 2, 2, 2],
    [0, 6, 7, 1],
    [0, 10, 12, 0]
]

results = []
for a in NL:
    results.append((5*a[0]) + (3*a[1]) - (29*a[2]) - (8*a[3]))

print(min(results))
# -318

print(results.index(min(results)))
# 2
```

Comment: Yes exactly but I need to print the list which give this result

Comment: Use `print(results.index(min(results)))`. See the updated answer

Comment: Sure with my pleasure